# Can't replace readed unicode chars to others in a text

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I'm trying to do a parser in Python3, which replace special spanish characters that don't appear in english alphabet. To do this, I have a csv  text file with all transformations (encoded in utf-8):

\u00c1,\u0041

\u00c9,\u0045

...

\u00fc,\u0075

But when I run the parser doesn't do anything. On the other hand, if I do this, works perfectly:

```
text.replace('\u00c1', '\u0041')
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from csv import reader

class Parser():

    def __init__(self, lang):
        self.lang = lang

    def replace(self, text):
        with open('./data/{}/replace.csv'.format(self.lang), 'r') as file:
            csvreader = reader(file)
            for l in csvreader:
                # text = text.replace('\u00f1','\u006e') This works
                text = text.replace(l[0],l[1])
        return text

def main():
    myparser = Parser('spanish')
    with open('/home/marco/Escritorio/ejemplo.txt', 'r') as file:
        text = file.read()
        print(myparser.replace(text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why remove accents?  año = year and ano = anus.  Python 3 can handle Unicode very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the CSV file in binary mode and then convert each line from "escaped unicode", e.g. `'\\u00c1'`, to unicode (type `str` in Python 3) *before* the CSV reader gets it's hands on the data:

```
def replace(self, text):
    with open('./data/{}/replace.csv'.format(self.lang), 'rb') as f:
        csvreader = reader(line.decode('unicode_escape') for line in f)
        for l in csvreader:
            text = text.replace(l[0], l[1])
    return text
```

Using `str.decode('unicode_escape')` will decode the incoming data from escaped unicode, into it's unicode encoding. The decoding will be memory efficient because it makes use of a generator which avoids reading the entire CSV into memory. Once that is done the CSV module will handle the data as unicode, and the string replacement should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to decompose the original text characters into their unaccented character and its accent mark.  Next encode to ASCII ignoring errors and it will remove all the non-ASCII accent marks.  Decode it again to get it back to Unicode if needed.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s ='áéíóúüñ'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFD',s)
'a\u0301e\u0301i\u0301o\u0301u\u0301u\u0308n\u0303'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFD',s).encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
b'aeiouun'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFD',s).encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('ascii')
'aeiouun'
```

Comment: Finally I chose this module for my purpose.